# Merging two data sets based on Site and then nearest Time in R

Tags: r, time, merge, location

I have a file that shows the time at which a species was sighted (timeofOccurance) at different sites and I would like to merge it with the gps location recorded nearest to that time at that site (GPSTime). I have provided an example below. The actual data set is quite large.

```
Abundance
Site     TimeofOccurance     Species
1         11:00               a
1         12:00               b
2         14:05               a
3         16:00               c
```

```
GPS
Site      GPS Time       Longitude     Latitude
1         11:01           X1            Y1
1         11:06           X2            Y2
1         12:00           X3            Y3
2         14:07           X5            Y5
2         14:15           X6            Y6
3         16:01           X8            Y8
```

Which would give the ideal output of:

```
AbundanceGPS
Site     TimeofOccurance       Species     Longitude     Latitude
1         11:00                 a          X1            Y1
1         12:00                 b          X3            Y3
2         14:05                 a          X5            Y5
3         16:00                 c          X8            Y8
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
Abundance %>% 
   inner_join(GPS %>% 
                mutate(nearest_time = str_extract(floor_date(lubridate::ymd_hms(str_c(Sys.Date(), `GPS Time`, sep = ' ')), unit = '5 mins'), '..:..:..')), 
              by = c('TimeofOccurance' = 'nearest_time')) %>% select('Site' = Site.x, TimeofOccurance, Species, Longitude, Latitude)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   Site TimeofOccurance Species Longitude Latitude
  <dbl> <time>          <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
1     1 11:00           a       X1        Y1      
2     1 12:00           b       X3        Y3      
3     2 14:05           a       X5        Y5      
4     3 16:00           c       X8        Y8
```